Issues with PHP statements during Coinbase Commerce payment
I am having issues with some simple PHP statements after receiving payment via crypto using Coinbase Commerce API. The payment is going through and the page is redirecting to the payment_complete page but it refuses to update the orders in my checkout table...
I have tried adding some lines to log the bugs, but it's also refusing to create the debug.log file... so I cannot see where the script is failing, and I can't monitor console because it redirects etc.
The issue appears to be with the webhook script, for some reason its skipping past it and not updating the items in checkout.
This is how I am rendering in the coinbase pay button:
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

try {
// Query to get the items from the checkout table for the current user
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT product FROM checkout WHERE userID = :userID");
$stmt->execute(['userID' => $userID]);

$items = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Check if there are items in the cart
if (count($items) > 1) {
    // For multiple items, join the titles into a single string separated by commas
    $description = implode(', ', array_column($items, 'product'));
} elseif (count($items) === 1) {
    // If there's only one item, use its title directly
    $description = $items[0]['product'];
} else {
    // If no items are found, set a default description
    $description = "No items found";
}

} catch (PDOException $e) {
// Handle any errors in the connection or query
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
exit();
}

// Set up the cURL request to the Coinbase API
// Set up the cURL request to the Coinbase API
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(
array (
    'name' => 'TL',  // The name of your business or checkout
    'description' => $description,  // Dynamically generated description of the items
    'local_price' => 
    array (
        'amount' => $totalprice['totPrice'],  // Total price of all items (use your original total price variable)
        'currency' => 'GBP',  // Currency code
    ),
    'pricing_type' => 'fixed_price',  // Pricing model (fixed in this case)
    'metadata' => 
    array (
        'customer_id' => $userID,  // Pass the userID as requested
        'customer_name' => $useremail,  // Customer's email or identifier (from session or checkout)
    ),
    'redirect_url' => 'https://www.my-site.co.uk/Checkout/payment_complete.php',  // URL to redirect after successful payment
    'cancel_url' => 'https://www.my-site.co.uk/Checkout/payment_cancelled.php',  // URL to redirect if payment is canceled
    'webhook_url' => 'https://www.my-site.co.uk/Checkout/PHP/coinbase_webhook.php'  // Webhook URL for payment confirmation
)
));

// Set headers for the Coinbase API request
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-Cc-Api-Key: MY-API-KEY';  // Your Coinbase API key
$headers[] = 'X-Cc-Version: 2018-03-22';  // Coinbase API version
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Execute the cURL request and get the response
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch);

// Decode the JSON response from Coinbase
$response = json_decode($result, true);

// Extract the hosted URL from the response to redirect the user
$letssee = $response['data']['hosted_url'];

// Output the payment button/link to the user
echo "<a id='byee' class='leggo2' href='$letssee'><b>Pay with Crypto</b></a>";
?>

and this is my coinbase_webhook.php backend file for confirming transaction and updating item(s) in checkout table:
<?php
session_start();
// DB connect //
require_once '/var/www/vhosts/my-site.co.uk/httpdocs/include/PHP/main.php';

// Set error handling
ini_set('display_errors', 0); // Disable error output to the client
ini_set('log_errors', 1); // Enable error logging
ini_set('error_log', '/var/www/vhosts/my-site.co.uk/httpdocs/Checkout/debug.log');
error_reporting(E_ALL); // Report all errors

// Log script start
file_put_contents('/var/www/vhosts/my-site.co.uk/httpdocs/Checkout/debug.log', "Script started at " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

// Coinbase Webhook Listener to handle crypto payment confirmation

// Read the incoming webhook data
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$signature = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CC_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE'];

// Verify the Coinbase signature to ensure it's a legit request
$shared_secret = 'MY-API-KEY'; // Get this from Coinbase Dashboard
$computed_signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $shared_secret);

if (hash_equals($signature, $computed_signature)) {
$event = json_decode($payload, true);
error_log("Received webhook event: " . print_r($event, true), 3, "/var/www/vhosts/my-site.co.uk/httpdocs/Checkout/debug.log");

// Check if the event is 'charge:confirmed'
if ($event['event']['type'] == 'charge:confirmed') {
    $paymentDetails = $event['event']['data'];

    // Extract necessary data
    $orderID = 'TL-' . bin2hex(random_bytes(5)); // Generate unique order ID
    $userID = $paymentDetails['metadata']['customer_id']; // Retrieve userID from metadata
    $amount = $paymentDetails['pricing']['local']['amount'];
    $currency = $paymentDetails['pricing']['local']['currency'];

    // Connect to the database using PDO (ensure you have the $dbh variable defined)
    try {
        $userID = $_SESSION['sessionID'];
        // Update the checkout records
        $paytype = "Crypto";
        $confirmationStatus = "Confirmed"; // This is what you want to store in the confirmation column
        $ordprogress = "75"; // Update the order progress as needed
        
        $updateStmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE checkout SET paytype = :paytype, confirmation = :confirmation, ordprogress = :ordprogress WHERE userID = :userID");
        $updateStmt->bindParam(':paytype', $paytype, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $updateStmt->bindParam(':confirmation', $confirmationStatus, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $updateStmt->bindParam(':ordprogress', $ordprogress, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $updateStmt->bindParam(':userID', $userID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        
        // Attempt to execute the update statement
        if (!$updateStmt->execute()) {
            // Log the SQL error if the update fails
            error_log("Failed to update checkout table. Error: " . implode(", ", $updateStmt->errorInfo()) . "\n", 3, "/var/www/vhosts/my-site.co.uk/httpdocs/Checkout/debug.log");
            throw new Exception("Failed to update checkout table.");
        }
        error_log("Checkout updated for userID: $userID\n", 3, "/var/www/vhosts/my-site.co.uk/httpdocs/Checkout/debug.log");

        http_response_code(200); // Respond with 200 OK
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log("Error occurred: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n", 3, "/var/www/vhosts/my-site.co.uk/httpdocs/Checkout/debug.log");
        http_response_code(500); // Internal server error
    }
}
} else {
// Invalid signature, possible attack
error_log("Invalid signature received\n", 3, "/var/www/vhosts/my-site.co.uk/httpdocs/Checkout/debug.log");
http_response_code(400); // Bad request
}
?>


You can use the "preserve log" feature in your browser's Developer Tools to keep the console and network logs visible even after a redirect or postback. That might help you to see more easily what's going on. (I assume that's what you meant by can't monitor console because it redirects, rather than any other type of console)

You are trying to access the user's PHP session in your webhook script - but of course that can not work. This is a request made by Coinbase's servers to your server - the user's browser (whose job it would be to send the session ID, so that your PHP knows which session to pick up again) is not involved in that request. You have no session ID available at this point - so PHP will only create a new, empty session.

@C3roe I have updated the question and added the userID to metadata but it still doesn't work.. the payment and everything works but it completely ignores the webhook script

Have you given the correct URL for your webhook to begin with? The other two URLs you got there, do not have /PHP/ in the path, this one does - is that intentional, or a mistake?

@C3roe Yes the file paths are correct, the checkout.php and crypto_pay_button.php are both in Checkout folder and webhook file is in PHP folder in Checkout folder, should this be different?

No, it is up to you where you put your scripts. I just wanted to make sure this was intentional, and you didn't specify a wrong URL that doesn't even exist in your system. Okay, next - have you properly registered your webhook URL? And if so - check your server's access log, to see if any requests for that URL reach your server in the first place.

@C3roe Not sure what you mean by this have you properly registered your webhook URL? How do I register it? You mean whitelist it in Coinbase Commerce or?

That part, https://docs.cdp.coinbase.com/commerce-onchain/docs/webhooks#subscribing-to-a-webhook

@C3roe Thanks for your help, I ended up fixing the problem, the issue was due to the redirection when using www. or not, so I had to add the exact file-path for the endpoint file with the www. included... and then the test notification gave a 200 response and then the rest of the script finally started working correctly... thank you for your time and effort, I really appreciate it!
